# Priority values

Tags: math

We are developing software, where the users have to assign priority numbers (integers) to jobs. Our basic question is if a high priority should be done with a high or low number (and vice-versa for low priority)? This is software to be used by other developers and we want to do what is most natural to the majority.

We have looked around and found both systems are being used and we also have different opinions internally.

What do you prefer?

Sorry if the tag is not good, but it is the best I could find.

Comment: I think everyone expects #1 to be the highest priority. But I think this is OT here and will get moved to programmers.

Comment: @unapersson: Obviously not. I for one can't make up my mind either. 2 is higher than 1, so wouldn't have a task with priority 2 a higher priority? OTOH, your interpretation of the numbers (as ranking) makes sense as well.

Comment: This is much more a psychology question. Possible other tags are design (it is most certainly not math). You can just create an option, and let users pick if you want, or flip a coin.

Comment: @delnan "It's Number One! It's Top Of The Pops!" But I guess this only works for UK residents of a certain age.

Comment: @Uffe The other possibility is to allow users to define their own priorities in terms of yours. So if yours have 3 as the highest, you could allow them to say High = 3, Medium = 2, Low = 1. In fact, most issue tracking systems provide something like this as standard.

Comment: I think it is off-topic for here and programmers, as it is totally subjective (and not the type of subjective programmers accepts really).

Answer (score 6):

It really depends on how you present the value to the user. If you present it as kind of a ranking, then 1 would be "better"/higher ranked than 2. But if you instead present it as a kind of "weight" then 2 would be "heavier" than 1. So it's more a matter of how you present it (be sure to be consistent with your choice).

Put personally, I have the feeling that the ranking system is more intuitive than a "weight" system. You normally think about the most important things, and you want to put them at the front, or handle them "first". Thus starting with 1 for high priorities and going to larger numbers for lower priorities seems more natural.

Comment: By default it is a ranking, with the option that users can assign weights. If we use 1 = highest priority, we end up with the highest weight on the lowest numbers and that is confusing.

Answer (score 5):

I think that DarkDust does a good job of capturing the ambiguity that causes why people do it differently.  My advice is, for whichever convention you choose, annotate the word "priority" with an indication of the convention you chose.  Say "priority rank" if lower values proceed first, and "priority weight" or "priority level" if higher values proceed first.  Avoid "priority number", as you are implicitly talking about a quantity with a direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding numbers for more priority levels, then it's easier to add higher numbers the the end of the queue.  If someone wants to make something a higher priority than a listed 1, then you have to shuffle the numbers.  Of course, this is pretty implementation specific.

Comment: If you make priority levels be floating point numbers, then people can insert as many gradations of priority as they want.